# composer how to define a version for a package

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a composer package, now I want to make a version for the package
and call it when update composer. like this

```
composer update 1.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Versioning using git tags

Assuming you will host that package in a git repository, you can use tags as composer versions. If you create a tag `v1.0.0` in your git repository, you can use that one for your composer update command and version definition.

```
{
    "require": {
        "your/package": "1.0.0"
    }
}

composer update your/package
```

For further details on that versioning you can refer to the manual [over here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#tags).

## Versioning using git branches

Secondly, you can use git branches for your version management. Basically, its the same schema as when using git tags: a branch name `v1.0.0` will be used when executing the update, assuming your `composer.json` contains `"your/package" : "1.0.0"`.

For further details you can again refer to the manual [over here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches).

## Versioning in manually created packages

If you do not use a git repo but want to create the packages manually, you can use the `composer.json` file for versioning. Simply add the `version` attribute to the json schema like explained [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version). **Please note**, that adding the version manually is not recommended if your VCS allows tagging / branching.

Comment: The command `composer update 1.0.0` is invalid. You cannot update to a VERSION, you can only update A PACKAGE, several of them by mentioning more, or all of them by only typing `composer update`.

Comment: @Sven You are right - did not really notice that. I ammended my answer.